# Can a Job DSL script be tested

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

Ideally I'd like to be able to invoke the script with some kind of unit test before I have it execute on a Jenkins.

Is there any way to test a Job DSL script other than having jenkins run it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Besides the examples in [job-dsl-gradle-example](https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example), you can also go a step further and write tests for individual files or jobs. For example let's assume you have a job configuration file located in jobs/deployJob.groovy

```groovy
import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptLoader
import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.MemoryJobManagement
import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.ScriptRequest
import spock.lang.Specification

class TestDeployJobs extends Specification {

    def 'test basic job configuration'() {
        given:
        URL scriptURL = new File('jobs').toURI().toURL()
        ScriptRequest scriptRequest = new ScriptRequest('deployJob.groovy', null, scriptURL)
        MemoryJobManagement jobManagement = new MemoryJobManagement()

        when:
        DslScriptLoader.runDslEngine(scriptRequest, jobManagement)

        then:
        jobManagement.savedConfigs.each { String name, String xml ->
            with(new XmlParser().parse(new StringReader(xml))) {
                // Make sure jobs only run manually
                triggers.'hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger'.spec.text().isEmpty()
                // only deploy every environment once at a time
                concurrentBuild.text().equals('false')
                // do a workspace cleanup
                buildWrappers.'hudson.plugins.ws__cleanup.PreBuildCleanup'
                // make sure masked passwords are active
                !buildWrappers.'com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.maskpasswords.MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper'.isEmpty()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way you are able to go through every XML node you want to make sure to have all the right values set.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [job-dsl-gradle-example](https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example). The repo contains a [test](https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example/blob/master/src/test/groovy/com/dslexample/JobScriptsSpec.groovy) for DSL scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it in the same way as [crasp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533886/crasp) but using Jenkins test harness as explained in [Jenkins Unit Test page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Unit+Test), which is slower but would work with auto-generated DSL giving syntax errors as explained [here](https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example/blob/master/src/test/groovy/com/dslexample/JobScriptsSpecAlternative.groovy#L16).

After setting the code as explained [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Testing-DSL-Scripts), you can just do a test like this one:

```
@Unroll
void 'check descriptions #file.name'(File file) {
    given:
    JobManagement jobManagement = new JenkinsJobManagement(System.out, [:], new File('.'))
    Jenkins jenkins = jenkinsRule.jenkins

    when:
    GeneratedItems items = new DslScriptLoader(jobManagement).runScript(file.text)

    then:
    if (!items.jobs.isEmpty()) {
        items.jobs.each { GeneratedJob generatedJob ->
            String text = getItemXml(generatedJob, jenkins)
            with(new XmlParser().parse(new StringReader(text))) {
                // Has some description
                !description.text().isEmpty()
            }
        }
    }

    where:
    file << TestUtil.getJobFiles()
}
```